# How to display page number if total page greater than 1?

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm using XSL-FO to generate PDF documents with one or more pages. However, if my document has one page I want to hide the `{pageNumber}/{totalPage}` (the **red rectangle area** in the below picture), and only display when `{totalPage} > 1`. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a different `fo:simple-page-master` for the single page that uses a different `region-name` for its `fo:region-after`.
- Add an `fo:page-sequence-master` that selects the new `fo:simple-page-master` for the single page using `page-position="only"`. (See [XSL-FO Different header/footer depending on page-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366990/xsl-fo-different-header-footer-depending-on-page-position?rq=1#), https://stackoverflow.com/a/58343013/4092205, and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#page-position.)
- When you generate the `fo:static-content` that you direct to the `fo:region-after` for regular pages, generate another `fo:static-content` *without* the `fo:page-number` and direct that to the `fo:region-after` for the `fo:simple-page-master` for the single page.
- When the formatter works out that the document fits on a single page, it will use the `fo:simple-page-master` for the single page, and that page will use the `fo:static-content` that has a `flow-name` that matches the `region-name` of its `fo:region-after`.

So that's a few steps, but that's because there's some flexibility in what you can do with `fo:page-sequence-master` selecting different page masters.

Comment: Excellent Tony, unbelievable, `page-position="only"` , it works perfect, I spent a whole day to find this solution, thank you so much!